Wait for a subprocess to start
When I start Davinci Resolve, while it is loading it starts a subprocess called Resolve.
Then when it finishes loading, this sub-process closes and opens another called Project Manager.

import subprocess
import time
import psutil


for proc in psutil.process_iter(['pid', 'name']):
    if proc.info['name'] == process_name:
        return True
return False

print(“Waiting for the 'Project Manager to open' sub-process”)
while not is_process_running("Project Manager.exe"):
    time.sleep(1)  # Aguarda 1 segundo antes de verificar novamente

print("Subprocess 'Project Manager' open ")

However, there is something wrong with the code, and I have no idea what it is.
I've tried using psutil, but I don't know if it's really necessary to do what I want, or if there are internal Windows commands that can do it properly.
Also, is there a faster and more reliable way to check if the Project Manager subprocess has been opened and try to check again than using time.sleep(1)?

Do you control either Resolve or Project Manager, or are they 3rd-party apps?  Are either written in Python?

@MatthewFlaschen Resolve and Project Manager are sub-processes of the Davinci Resolve application, not third-party applications. I don't know if they were written in Python, I just need to check if the Project Manager subprocess has been opened, because when I start the program, it takes a moment for the Project Manager subprocess to be opened :D

You can use the children method of a psutil.Process object to at least avoid to iterate over all available processes of the OS.

@MichaelButscher  entered a separate answer (I couldn't tag you) trying to use the children method, but it didn't work

Better update the question instead as this isn't really an answer so it may be downvoted and/or deleted. The process name is usually the filename of the executable (including the suffix .exe) with which the program was started. A short search indicates that the filename (and therefore process name) of DaVinci Resolve is just resolve.exe.

Do it this way
import psutil
import time

def check_child_process(parent_name, child_name):
    for proc in psutil.process_iter(['pid', 'name']):
        if proc.info['name'] == parent_name:
            parent = psutil.Process(proc.info['pid'])
            for child in parent.children(recursive=True):
                if child.name() == child_name:
                    return True
    return False

parent_process_name = "explorer.exe" #change to your proccess name
child_process_name = "EXCEL.EXE" #change to your child proccess name

while True:
    if check_child_process(parent_process_name, child_process_name):
        print(f"{child_process_name} is running as a child of {parent_process_name}.")
    else:
        print(f"{child_process_name} is not running as a child of {parent_process_name}.")
    time.sleep(3)  # Check every 3 seconds

I don't have your program, but with Excel it works, remember that names are case sensitive, to check your parent and child process names use
wmic process get Caption,ParentProcessId,ProcessId 

or
wmic process get Caption,ParentProcessId,ProcessId | findstr /i "<name of process or executable>"

for a more specific search, and
wmic process where (ParentProcessId=<number of parent PID>) get Caption,ProcessId

in windows command line.
Result closing and opening Excel
EXCEL.EXE is running as a child of explorer.exe.
EXCEL.EXE is running as a child of explorer.exe.
EXCEL.EXE is not running as a child of explorer.exe.
EXCEL.EXE is not running as a child of explorer.exe.
EXCEL.EXE is not running as a child of explorer.exe.
EXCEL.EXE is running as a child of explorer.exe.
EXCEL.EXE is running as a child of explorer.exe.
EXCEL.EXE is running as a child of explorer.exe.
EXCEL.EXE is running as a child of explorer.exe.


When taking the ParentProcessId of Resolve.exe and trying to get the name of the childprocess with the third code, several processes are returned (OneDrive.exe, EXCEL.exe, Resolve.exe and others with their respective processID). The childProcess of Resolve.exe, which is the Project Manager, is not returned. I tried replacing ParentProcessID with the ProcessID of Resolve.exe, so fuscript.exe is returned, which is related to Resolve, but it's not the Project Manager, I even closed fuscript.exe to see if it closed the Project Manager, but nothing happened : /

@Phill You should use Resolve.exe PID in the second command as parent id to find its children. The parent PID of Resolve.exe will be svchost.exe or explorer.exe and those have multiple children because are program launchers of windows.

Thank you for your patience in helping me. I created a separate reply explaining what's going on, but I couldn't tag you.

@Phill To identify the executable of "Project Manager" in task manager, if it opens in a simplified view, click on More details at the bottom. Go to the Details tab, You will see a list of processes, the Name column shows the executable name of each process. Add More Columns (Optional): Right-click on any column header, select columns from the context menu, e.g. description or package name, to identify the process mentioned.
And don't post comments as an answer, delete it and comment here.

(repost because there was a comment as a reply) I used the PID of Resolve.exe in the second command (now it's the third command because you edited it). It only returns fuscript.exe, there is no Project Manager. In addition, when interacting with the program, I made it open a new child process different from the Project Manager to do a test, so I ran the code again and it continues to track only fuscript.exe as a child Process. https://i.sstatic.net/mLrRoqFD.png

(repost because there was a comment as a reply But in the task manager, DaVinci Resolve is shown as having the Project Manager and DaVinci Resolve Studio - Untitled Project inside it. The strange thing is that in the task manager there is no mention of CPU/RAM/GPU usage for these 2 child processes. Note that Microsoft Edge has a child process with CPU/RAM/GPU usage, but DaVinci Resolve does not. So are they not child processes?
https://i.sstatic.net/oTWHDGiA.png

I did the new procedure you taught. There are no executables named Project Manager or DaVinci Resolve Studio - Untitled Project inside. The only executable with a description associated with DaVinci is Resolve.exe.  And the Package Name column is empty for most executables.

Maybe I'll try installing that program later to check what is the subprocess executable.

I used WinSpy and it was able to find the Project Manager window, and in detail it says that it is associated with the Resolve.exe process.
https://i.sstatic.net/zOVbykJ5.png
Thanks for helping me :D
